# Assigning variable to another cell based on a value that is found

Tags: excel, vba

I have set a variable equal to a value ("Outlt") using the find command. I would like to set the value of the cell to the left of it in column A, equal to another variable called "Outnode"

I have tried several different codes using offset but I keep getting an error. Can anyone help me assign "Outnode" to the cell to the left of cell that I would find "Outlt" in? Am I not properly setting "Findout" to the cell that I found the word "Outlt" in? Thank you.

```
Sub FindOffsetvalue ()
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim Findout As range
    Dim Outnode As range

    Sheets(1).Activate

    If Trim(number) <> "" Then
    With Sheets(1).range("B:B")
                Set Findout = .Find(What:="Outlt", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not Findout Is Nothing Then
                   Findout.Select
                Else
                    MsgBox "Nothing found"
                End If
    End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            If Not Findout Is Nothing Then
               Findout.Select
               Set Outnode = Findout.Offset(0, -1)
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
```